# Ignore globals in a Python function

Tags: python, global-variables, ipython, jupyter-notebook

I love IPython Notebook and I use it a lot for exploratory data analysis, where I try tons of different things until something *works*. However, quite often I end up doing the same mistake.. Let me idiotize an example:

I usually start doing tests in IPython like this:

```
a = 10
print a + 5
```

Until I get the desired result. Once I got it working, I tend to reformulate the code as a function:

```
def add5(b):
    return b + 5
```

Which would be the proper redefinition.. however, as the code is sometimes quite complex (and large), I end up with renaming errors and instead  write:

```
def add5(b):
    return a + 5
```

Note the `a` instead of the renamed `b`. This function will return a value as long as `a` exists in the workspace (which does). This mistake is quite annoying, sometimes takes a long time to realise what's wrong, and sometimes is even impossible to realise that something is wrong due to the complex nature of the function.

Is there any cell magic, decorator or something else to force a function to ignore global variables?

I would love something like:

```
@ignore_globals   ## or %%ignore_globals
def add5(b):
    return a + 5
```

so that the above would prompt an error if `a` is not defined inside the function (either at definition or at runtime). Assuming that `a` does exist in the workspace (`globals()`).

This introduces another problem in practice, which is that imported *modules* and other used defined *functions* and *classes* are also in `globals` (and should be accessible)..